Manga where the main character finds a dragon
I'm searching for a manga I read a long time ago out of pure curiosity. It's not an isekai, but it takes place in a modern setting where magic and other races exist. The main character is the son of a legendary hero and ends up finding a baby dragon (or maybe a dragon egg, I'm not sure).
He keeps it and goes on an adventure. Later, he becomes friends with a rich girl and princess. He saves the princess from a terrorist assault orchestrated by a man manipulated by a demon who hates his father.

Welcome to SF&F.  This question needs some more detail.  Can you add in specific descriptions of plot elements or o the characters?  Even character names will help.  At the moment it is a bit general to try to identify.  See https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/tips-for-asking-story-identification-questions for ideas of how to improve the question to help us to identify the story.

Note that the question may be closed for lack of clarity.  When you edit it and add in more details, it can be reopened.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?

I believe it's Kyuubo: Suterareteta Dragon Hirotta, with an English title of [Urgent Request] How to Take Care of an Abandoned Dragon?
The plot matches the description given: a guy whose father (who is half-orc and half-ogre) was a hero in the past, and whose mother is half-angel and half-demon, but he himself cannot use magic, though he is very strong and incredibly tough (someone tries to hit him in the back with a sword and it just breaks).
He finds a baby dragon (which turns out to be a rare breed of dragon as well) in a plastic bag in a pile of garbage in front of a convenience store, and it sets off the series of events described.
